# Taildwind render en next.js 13

Tags: next.js, tailwind

Estoy intentando renderizar un componente  y otro para escritorio, para esto uso un custom hook que detecta window.matchMedia(query).matches y ver si está en mobile en cierta resolución, la cuestión es que me sale un error rarísimo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el componente de MenuDesktop + MenuMobile [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wispy-hooks-j9tche?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A7%2C18)